# How can I listen for two keys' codes combination in TextArea?

Tags: java, gwt

My code is like this:

```
final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
       if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_CTRL) {
          textArea.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
          public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
             if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                foo();
            }
         }
     });
    }
  }
});
```

I need to listen for `CTRL`+`ENTER` combination,
problem is `foo()` is calling when I press `ENTER`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the CTRL key was depressed when the given event occurred by calling its `isControlKeyDown`.

```
 public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {  
    if (event.isControlKeyDown()) {
         if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
             //do something here
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check for stuff like control, alt, and meta:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int modifiers = e.getModifiersEx();
    String tmpString = KeyEvent.getModifiersExText(modifiers);
    final int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    int id = e.getID();
    char c = 0;
    if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED)
        c = e.getKeyChar();
    if (!e.isAltDown() && !e.isControlDown() && !e.isMetaDown())
        normalKey(keyCode);
    else if (!e.isAltDown() && e.isControlDown() && !e.isMetaDown())
        controlKey(keyCode, e.isShiftDown());
    else
        log.info("keycode not processed: " + e.getKeyCode() + ' ' + id + ' ' + c + ' ' + tmpString + ' ' + e.isAltDown() + ' ' + e.isControlDown() + ' '
                + e.isShiftDown() + ' ' + e.isMetaDown());
    lastKeyCode=keyCode;
}
```

Comment: The question is about GWT, not AWT.

Comment: oops. try: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/KeyboardListener.html#onKeyDown%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20char,%20int%29